# How to set this in separate in onsen ui framework?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

How can i manage when i am click on the submit the button the show me the sliding menu only show after submit menu not show the front page how can manage it .???? using  **onsen ui and angularjs**

**Main Page**

```
 <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
      <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center" >
            <ons-icon icon="user">&nbsp;Login</ons-icon>
          </div>
              </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-list>
          <ons-list-item>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item >
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item>
            <input type="password" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
          </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
        <div class="content-padded" align="center" style="margin-top:10px;">
          <ons-button modifier="medium"
                        onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('dashboard.html', { animation : 'slide' } )"> Submit </ons-button>
          <ons-button modifier="medium"
                        onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('forgot_password.html', { animation : 'slide' } )"> Forgot Password </ons-button>
        </div>
         </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
```

**This is Sliding menu**

```
<ons-sliding-menu
    menu-page="dashboard.html" main-page="page1.html" side="left"
    var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">

        </ons-sliding-menu>
<ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
    <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
            <ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon>
           Home
        </ons-list-item>
<!--      <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent">sss</ons-toolbar>-->
<ons-list-header>From Demo Real Estate</ons-list-header>
      <ons-list class="bottom-menu-list">
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
            <ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon>
           Search Residential
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page4.html', {closeMenu: true})">
         <ons-icon icon="fa-search"></ons-icon>   Search Commercial
        </ons-list-item>
<ons-list-header>From Demo Real Estate</ons-list-header>


         <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
         <ons-icon icon="fa-user"></ons-icon>
         Login or Register
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-book"></ons-icon>
          About Us
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-phone"></ons-icon>
          Feedback
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-edit"></ons-icon>
        Sell/Rent Property
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
```

Help me!!!!!!!!!!

and thanx in advance ..:)

**This is my Hole Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CodePen - Navigator</title>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://onsenui.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsenui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://onsenui.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsen-css-components.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center" >
        <ons-icon icon="user">&nbsp;Login</ons-icon>
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
      </ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item >
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
      </ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item>
        <input type="password" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
    <div class="content-padded" align="center" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <ons-button modifier="medium"
                    onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('dashboard.html', { animation : 'slide' } )"> Submit </ons-button>
      <ons-button modifier="medium"
                    onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('forgot_password.html', { animation : 'slide' } )"> Forgot Password </ons-button>
    </div>
    <p align="center">Don't Have the account? Please <a onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('register.html', { animation : 'slide' } )" href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:#4282CC"> Register Here</a></p>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
<ons-template id="register.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Register</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center"> <br />
      <ons-page>
        <ons-list>
          <ons-list-item>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:58px; width: 100%;">
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item>
            <ons-row>
              <ons-col width="90px"> <span style="color: #666">Gender</span> </ons-col>
              <ons-col>
                <div style="float: right; padding-right: 16px;">
                  <label class="radio-button">
                  <input type="radio" name="level">
                  <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
                  Male
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio-button">
                  <input type="radio" name="level">
                  <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
                  Female
                  </label>
                </div>
              </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
          </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
        <div class="content-padded">
          <ons-button modifier="large" onclick=""> Sign Up </ons-button>
        </div>
      </ons-page>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="forgot_password.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Forgot Password</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-page>
      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
      <div class="content-padded">
        <ons-button modifier="large" onclick=""> Forgot Password</ons-button>
      </div>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<!-- =========================== Dashboard Front Pannel ========================================-->
<ons-template id="dashboard.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">
        <ons-icon icon="user">&nbsp;Dashboard</ons-icon>
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-page >
      <div class="content-padded" >
        <ons-button modifier="large">
          <div align="left">Latest Shipment List</div>
        </ons-button>
      </div>
      <table id="responsive-example-table" class="large-only bordare" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" width="98%" style="margin:10px;" >
        <tbody>
          <tr align="center">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>AWB NO</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Pickup Date</th>
            <th>Dilvery Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Print Lable</th>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td>01</td>
            <td><a href="" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('booking_view.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">10000252</a></td>
            <td>Bikaner</td>
            <td>Japur</td>
            <td>10-5-2015</td>
            <td>10-5-2015</td>
            <td><span  class="col_bg_yellow">&nbsp;Pickup Scheduled&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td align="center"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dark_tabl" align="center">
            <td>02</td>
            <td><a href="" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('booking_view.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">10000252</a></td>
            <td>Bikaner</td>
            <td>Japur</td>
            <td>10-5-2015</td>
            <td>10-5-2015</td>
            <td><span  class="col_bg_yellow">&nbsp;Pickup Scheduled&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="" al><a href=""><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="content-padded" >
        <ons-button modifier="large">
          <div align="left">Latest Booking List</div>
        </ons-button>
      </div>
      <table id="responsive-example-table" class="large-only bordare" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" width="98%" style="margin:10px;">
        <tbody align="center">
          <tr align="center">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>AWB NO</th>
            <th>Booking Id</th>
            <th>Booking Date</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Product/Type</th>
            <th>Pay Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td>01</td>
            <td>10000252</td>
            <td>XKXCZN</td>
            <td>10-5-2015</td>
            <td>Rangareddy</td>
            <td>Prakasam</td>
            <td>Normal service</td>
            <td>Parcel</td>
            <td><span  class="col_bg_green">&nbsp;PAID&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><a href="" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('booking_view.html', { animation : 'slide' } )"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> &nbsp;<a href=""><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href=""><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dark_tabl" align="center">
            <td>02</td>
            <td>10000252</td>
            <td>XKXCZN</td>
            <td>10-5-2015</td>
            <td>Rangareddy</td>
            <td>Prakasam</td>
            <td>Normal service</td>
            <td>Parcel</td>
            <td><span  class="col_bg_red">&nbsp;DUE&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><a href="" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('booking_view.html', { animation : 'slide' } )"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> &nbsp;<a href=""><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href=""><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
<!--============================================================================================--> 

<!-- =======================================VIEW DETAILS FOR BOOKING =============================-->
<ons-template id="booking_view.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">TRACKING RESULT FOR AWB# {{users.slip_no}}</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" style="margin:10px;" >
      <tr>
        <td><b>Payment Status</b></td>
        <td><ons-button modifier="cta">Pending</ons-button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr  >
        <td colspan="5"><div > <br>
            <ons-button modifier="dark" style="width:99%; margin-left:5px;" > SHIPMENT DETAILS:<span>{{users.delivered}}</span> </ons-button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Schedule Delivery</b> {{user.origin}}</td>
        <td>{{users.expected_date | date: 'fullDate'}}, By End Of Day</td>
        <td><b>Last Location</b></td>
        <td>{{users.origin}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><div > <br>
            <ons-button modifier="dark" style="width:99%; margin-left:5px;" > DIMENSION DETAILS: </ons-button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Origin</b></td>
        <td>{{users.origin}}</td>
        <td><b>Destination</b></td>
        <td>{{users.destination}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Service</b></td>
        <td>{{users.service_id}}</td>
        <td><b>Shipped/Billed On</b></td>
        <td>{{users.pickup_date | date: 'fullDate'}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Type</b></td>
        <td>{{users.nrd}}</td>
        <td><b>Weight</b></td>
        <td>{{users.weight}}KG</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><div > <br>
            <ons-button modifier="dark" style="width:99%; margin-left:5px;" > SHIPPER DETAILS : </ons-button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td>{{users.sender_name}}</td>
        <td><b>Address</b></td>
        <td>{{users.sender_address}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><div > <br>
            <ons-button modifier="dark" style="width:99%; margin-left:5px;" > CONSINGER DETAILS : </ons-button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td>{{users.reciever_name}}</td>
        <td><b>Address</b></td>
        <td>{{users.reciever_address}}</td>
      </tr>
      <td colspan="5"><div > <br>
            <ons-button modifier="dark" style="width:99%; margin-left:5px;" > OTHER PARCEL DETAILS : </ons-button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td>{{users.reciever_name}}</td>
        <td><b>Address</b></td>
        <td>{{users.reciever_address}}</td>
      </tr>

            <td colspan="5"><div > <br>
            <ons-button modifier="dark" style="width:99%; margin-left:5px;" > PAYEMENT DETAILS : </ons-button>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Total Amount</b></td>
        <td>{{users.reciever_name}}</td>


      </tr>
              <td><b>Tax(3.9%)</b></td>
        <td>{{users.reciever_name}}</td>


      </tr>        <td><b>Net Amount</b></td>
        <td>{{users.reciever_name}}</td>


      </tr>
    </table>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
<!--============================================================================================--> 

<!--============================== Sliding Menu =================================================--> 


  <ons-sliding-menu
    menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" side="left"
    var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">
       </ons-sliding-menu>
  <ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
    <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="myNavigator.resetToPage('page-with-menu.html'), {closeMenu: true})">
            <ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon>
           Home
        </ons-list-item>
<ons-list-header>From Demo Real Estate</ons-list-header>
      <ons-list class="bottom-menu-list">
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
            <ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon>
           Search Residential
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page4.html', {closeMenu: true})">
         <ons-icon icon="fa-search"></ons-icon>   Search Commercial
        </ons-list-item>
<ons-list-header>From Demo Real Estate</ons-list-header>


         <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
         <ons-icon icon="fa-user"></ons-icon>
         Login or Register
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-book"></ons-icon>
          About Us
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-phone"></ons-icon>
          Feedback
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('login.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-edit"></ons-icon>
        Sell/Rent Property
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
<!--============================================================================================--> 

<script src='http://onsenui.io/OnsenUI/build/js/angular/angular.js'></script><script src='http://onsenui.io/OnsenUI/build/js/onsenui.js'></script> 
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `myNavigator.resetToPage('page-with-menu.html')` when the user has been validated. It will reset the page stack.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius i will try but not right answer can you edit the Question sir

Comment: Please make your question more clear and also what have you tried? There are many ways to implement a login prompt, one way is to use a navigator and reset the page stack when the user is logged in.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius i don't want to show sliding menu before log in, instead i want to show after log in on all pages.  in above code

Comment: Did you try with `resetToPage`?

Comment: @AndreasArgelius Yes but not working..

Comment: You can make a navigator with the login page and then when the user logs in do `resetToPage('main-page.html')`.

Comment: I think you are messing up with the IDs. After the login you are pointing to "dashboard.html", but this is just a page, not an ons-sliding-menu. You need to put your ons-sliding-menu inside a template with "id=slidingmenu.html", and the redirect to that ID after your login.

Comment: @FranDios   Can you Edit the code sir for more Explain.. i wil try but not set

Comment: @AndreasArgelius  i will try resetTopage this but doesn't work